# How to compare two table value using mysql query and matched value then print true false using alise filled

Tags: php, mysql

**one table is tbl_block**

[image]

**and second table is tbl_late_students**

[image]

**and output like this :**
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below using `left join` and `CASE WHEN`

```
select 
   a.enrollment_no,
   case when b.enrollment_no is null then 'false' else 'true' end as result 
from tbl_block a left join tbl_late_students b
on a.enrollment_no=b.enrollment_no
```

Comment: but i need simple query and i am using phpmyadmin sql

Comment: @mr.hir, it's a very basic simple query and it will execute properly in phpmyadmin - just execute this

Comment: display this error   Unrecognized keyword. (near "CASE" at position 32)
Unrecognized keyword. (near "WHEN" at position 37)

Comment: @mr.hir - you can check here https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6a4da34497b72cdbdad2d38081512f77